# Calculating values of preceding N days

Tags: r, panel-data, skew

I have following panel data, with dates, identifier codes, and returns. There are missing dates (non-trading days), but i've omitted that in the example data for simplicity.

| DATE | ASSET_CODE | RET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1990-01-01 | 1 | 0.12 |
| 1990-01-02 | 1 | 0.03 |
| 1990-01-03 | 1 | -0.11 |
| 1990-01-04 | 1 | 0.15 |
| 1990-01-05 | 1 | -0.10 |
| 1990-01-06 | 1 | 0.04 |
| 1990-01-07 | 1 | 0.10 |
| 1990-01-08 | 1 | 0.13 |
| 1990-01-09 | 1 | -0.12 |
| 1990-01-10 | 1 | 0.15 |
| 1990-01-11 | 1 | -0.08 |
| 1990-01-12 | 1 | 0.02 |
| 1990-01-13 | 1 | 0.14 |
| 1990-01-14 | 1 | -0.06 |
| 1990-01-15 | 1 | 0.01 |
| 1990-01-16 | 1 | -0.14 |
| 1990-01-17 | 1 | 0.06 |
| 1990-01-18 | 1 | -0.14 |
| 1990-01-19 | 1 | -0.13 |
| 1990-01-20 | 1 | -0.05 |
| 1990-01-21 | 1 | -0.13 |
| 1990-01-22 | 1 | 0.03 |
| 1990-01-23 | 1 | 0.07 |
| 1990-01-24 | 1 | -0.01 |
| 1990-01-25 | 1 | -0.07 |
| 1990-01-26 | 1 | 0.15 |
| 1990-01-27 | 1 | -0.12 |
| 1990-01-28 | 1 | 0.05 |
| 1990-01-29 | 1 | 0.15 |
| 1990-01-30 | 1 | -0.12 |
| 1990-01-31 | 1 | 0.05 |
| 1990-02-01 | 1 | -0.08 |
| 1990-02-02 | 1 | 0.08 |
| 1990-02-03 | 1 | -0.06 |
| 1990-02-04 | 1 | -0.06 |
| 1990-02-05 | 1 | -0.07 |
| 1990-01-01 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-02 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-03 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-04 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-05 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-06 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-07 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-08 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-09 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-10 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-11 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-12 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-13 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-14 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-15 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-16 | 2 | NA |
| 1990-01-17 | 2 | -0.17 |
| 1990-01-18 | 2 | 0.17 |
| 1990-01-19 | 2 | -0.20 |
| 1990-01-20 | 2 | -0.23 |
| 1990-01-21 | 2 | 0.00 |
| 1990-01-22 | 2 | 0.24 |
| 1990-01-23 | 2 | -0.16 |
| 1990-01-24 | 2 | 0.13 |
| 1990-01-25 | 2 | 0.18 |
| 1990-01-26 | 2 | -0.10 |
| 1990-01-27 | 2 | -0.26 |
| 1990-01-28 | 2 | 0.18 |
| 1990-01-29 | 2 | 0.27 |
| 1990-01-30 | 2 | 0.27 |
| 1990-01-31 | 2 | 0.09 |
| 1990-02-01 | 2 | -0.16 |
| 1990-02-02 | 2 | -0.16 |
| 1990-02-03 | 2 | -0.13 |
| 1990-02-04 | 2 | 0.14 |
| 1990-02-05 | 2 | 0.18 |

I want to calculate the skewness of the preceding 15-30 values in RET for each ASSET_CODE.

In other words, for asset 1 here, skewness can start to be calculated on 1990-01-16, as 15 preceding values are available. Then, on 1990-01-17, the last 16 values in RET are taken into account etc etc.

Beginning from 1990-01-31, the skewness is calculated based on the preceding 30 values of RET. So on 1990-02-05 for example, skewness is based on returns from 1990-01-06 to 1990-02-04

Comment: The `zoo` and `slider` packages are common ways to calculate rolling statistics of your choice based on a time window. data.table can do that as well. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Define `Skewness` which calculates the skewness if its argument has at least 15 non-NA's.  `list(-seq(30))` means use offsets -1 to -30 for each window and `partial=TRUE` means if there are not 30 rows available use however many there are.

```
library(dplyr)
library(e1071)
library(zoo)

Skewness <- function(x) {
  x <- na.omit(x)
  if (length(x) < 15) NA else skewness(x)
}

DF %>%
    mutate(roll = rollapply(RET, list(-seq(30)), Skewness, 
      fill = NA, partial = TRUE), .by = ASSET_CODE)
```

### Note

```
DF <-
structure(list(DATE = c("1990-01-01", "1990-01-02", "1990-01-03", 
"1990-01-04", "1990-01-05", "1990-01-06", "1990-01-07", "1990-01-08", 
"1990-01-09", "1990-01-10", "1990-01-11", "1990-01-12", "1990-01-13", 
"1990-01-14", "1990-01-15", "1990-01-16", "1990-01-17", "1990-01-18", 
"1990-01-19", "1990-01-20", "1990-01-21", "1990-01-22", "1990-01-23", 
"1990-01-24", "1990-01-25", "1990-01-26", "1990-01-27", "1990-01-28", 
"1990-01-29", "1990-01-30", "1990-01-31", "1990-02-01", "1990-02-02", 
"1990-02-03", "1990-02-04", "1990-02-05", "1990-01-01", "1990-01-02", 
"1990-01-03", "1990-01-04", "1990-01-05", "1990-01-06", "1990-01-07", 
"1990-01-08", "1990-01-09", "1990-01-10", "1990-01-11", "1990-01-12", 
"1990-01-13", "1990-01-14", "1990-01-15", "1990-01-16", "1990-01-17", 
"1990-01-18", "1990-01-19", "1990-01-20", "1990-01-21", "1990-01-22", 
"1990-01-23", "1990-01-24", "1990-01-25", "1990-01-26", "1990-01-27", 
"1990-01-28", "1990-01-29", "1990-01-30", "1990-01-31", "1990-02-01", 
"1990-02-02", "1990-02-03", "1990-02-04", "1990-02-05"), ASSET_CODE = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), RET = c(0.12, 0.03, -0.11, 0.15, 
-0.1, 0.04, 0.1, 0.13, -0.12, 0.15, -0.08, 0.02, 0.14, -0.06, 
0.01, -0.14, 0.06, -0.14, -0.13, -0.05, -0.13, 0.03, 0.07, -0.01, 
-0.07, 0.15, -0.12, 0.05, 0.15, -0.12, 0.05, -0.08, 0.08, -0.06, 
-0.06, -0.07, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.17, 0.17, -0.2, -0.23, 0, 0.24, -0.16, 0.13, 
0.18, -0.1, -0.26, 0.18, 0.27, 0.27, 0.09, -0.16, -0.16, -0.13, 
0.14, 0.18)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -72L))
```